# Div class not changing on scroll

Tags: javascript, class, scroll

I have a piece of plain text in my html code inside in a div. The div's class is 'intro'.

In my CSS, I have two classes for this piece of text:

```
.intro {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 3%;
display: none;
}

.introalt { 
 width: 100%;
margin-top: 3%;
display: block;
}
```

In my script, I have the following code because I want to change the class of the div to 'introalt' once I have scrolled a bit. Forgive if I am making rookie mistakes here, I'm not used to working with scripts.

```
$(function() {
var div = $(".intro");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 100) {
        div.removeClass('intro').addClass("introalt");
    }
   });
});
```

EDIT: Put the codepen up here: [View codepen](https://codepen.io/Djennis/pen/ZxQyvg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html doesn't exists any elements with class='inleding'.

so changed it to `var div = $(".intro");`

Then you forgot to add Jquery lib.

After fixed above issues, your codes works.

And I forked your codepen, [check this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEPXzg).

**Edit:** To display the rendered result well, I mades the position of the div is fixed. You can removed it in your project. (But I didn't do `position:fixed` in codepen.)

```js
$(function() {
    var div = $("#showup");
    $(window).scroll( function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 100) {
            div.removeClass('intro').addClass("introalt");
        }
        else {
            div.removeClass('introalt').addClass("intro");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
background-color:#f4f4f4;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.navbar {
    z-index: 50;
    height: 3em;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

.navbar ul {
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin-right: 7.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.navbar li {
    color: grey;
    margin-left: 2em;
    float: right;
}

li:hover {
  color: white;
}

.navbar img {
    margin-top: 0.6em;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    height: 55%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

#huidig {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #26c181;
}

h1.naam {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: 500;
    }

.header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}



.header h1{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2em;
    top: 3em;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.header p {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.65);
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.3em;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.header img {
    filter: brightness(80%);
    z-index: -10;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40em;

}

.intro {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    display: none;
}

.introalt { 
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 3%;
   display: block;
   position:fixed;
   top:50px;
   left:10px;
}


.intro h1 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #26c181;
}

.intro p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -1em
}

.lijn {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 4px solid #26c181;
    height: 15em;
    margin-top: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600|Roboto+Slab:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
    
<title>Thoun</title>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="navbar">
            <img src="./img/thoun_logo.png" alt="Logo" border="0">
        <h1 class="naam">THOUN</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Over ons</li>
            <li>Bedrijven</li>
            <li>Cases</li>
            <li>Levensstijl</li>
            <li>Locaties</li>
            <li id="huidig">Home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 
<div class ="header">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mT1nV7/foto3.jpg" alt="foto3" border="0">
    <h1> Waar heb je altijd al willen wonen?</h1>
    <p> Iedereen wil op een droomlocatie wonen,<br> maar vaak blijft het bij een droom.<br><br>
Tijd om wakker te worden.</p>
    
 </div>
    
    <div class="lijn"></div>
    
<div class="intro" id="showup">
    <h1>Maak kennis met tiny house</h1>
    <p> Tegenwoordig moet alles maar groter, sneller, en beter. <br>
Iedereen wil in de hipste hotspots wonen, midden in de grootste en drukste steden.<br>
Voor de mensen die hier geen zin meer in hebben, is er nu de tiny house.<br> Wil je wonen in de bergen, naast een prachtig meer? <br><br><strong> Geen probleem, alles is mogelijk.</strong></p>
 </div>
 
    <div class="lijn"></div>
    
    
    
    
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful @Sphnix, I added both the library and changed the position to fixed, but it still does not work. I tried comparing my code and your codepen but I do not see any differences. This is driving me insane :/

Comment: @DennisdeVries, does my codepen or above snippet meet your requirements? If yes, there should be something else wrong in your project. The codes in Codepen is your full codes in your project?

Comment: Yes, they do, they work perfectly in codepen. I just deleted all my code and copy-pasted every line you posted in the snippet; that still did not work. Is there any way I could upload my project files on this site and have you take a look at it? Sorry for being so stupid but I am really not seeing what is going wrong currently, because it doesn't even work if I copy-paste everything. The codes in my codepen are the full codes, yes.

Comment: Can you open the web console of your browser? then check if any error when you load the page and scroll the page.

Comment: And there is one `export` button at the left bottom of Codepen website, you can export it then test it in your computer.

Comment: Something weird is going on here. If I test it within the live preview of Dreamweaver, it works fine. If I copy all my Dreamweaver code into Codepen, it works fine. However, the moment I try to preview my code in Safari or Google Chrome, the script doesn't work anymore. I checked my browser settings and scrips are enabled. Also, when exporting the file out of codepen and trying to open that html file with Chrome, Chrome does nothing and doesn't even load up a new tab for the page. I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: @DennisdeVries check this [Chrome Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) to see how to debug your web.

Comment: wow the debugging console fixed it! Thank you so much. I have a bug in Dreamweaver that makes it show files as properly linked while they're not, I contacted Adobe Support about this last week and I thought it was fixed. The same was happening with te location of the script file. Thanks so much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put 'inleidingalt' class in addClass() instead of 'introalt'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, 'inleidingalt' is not part of my code, the div class is 'intro' and the alt class in my css is 'introalt'.

Comment: can you please put your html structure

Comment: @DennisdeVries there is no element with `class="inleiding"` in your codes of codepen.

Comment: @Sphinx I know, sorry for the confusion. There is no 'inleiding' class, there is only the 'intro' and 'introalt' classes, like I stated in the comment above

Comment: @DennisdeVries, updated my answer, you can check it in the snippet or the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging some dummy text out in your scroll function just to check the scroll function is working if not use something like below it's always what i use and works if it doesnt switch window.scroll to body.scroll you may have some weird overflow on your page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    //logic here
  });
});
```